# Web Services using C++

Tags: c++, mysql, web-services, qt, rest

I am building a server-client application that involves heavy signal processing (e.g. FFT). I have a working application written in C++/Qt, where everything (signal processing and other calculations) is done in client and server just sends raw data. Now I feel it would be easier to implement these features on the server. So, that maintenance becomes easier.

As I am doing signal processing, I think I should stick to C++ for performance. But I am open to new ideas. 
Constraints:

- I need type checking so javascript is out of discussion.
- Scaling includes adding more server and each server will have at the max
  10-12 users. So, Hardware cost is important. I cannot use x number of
  i7 processors.
- No option of using cloud services.

So, right now my question is as follows:

- How can I create web services using C++ for Linux server? (Although cross platform is not important, I would appreciate if I can achieve it.)

**EDIT** [02:09:2015]

Right now, I think the choice is between poco and C++ Rest SDK. I feel I should go for C++ Rest SDK. Mainly because it has only those features that I need. And Also it is supported by microsoft and uses boost internally. So, I feel in future, this might be well integreated with standard.

Comment: First you need to decide, what kind of API you want to provide. For SOAP you may use gSOAP toolkit. Don't use QtSoap because it is not supported and more complex.

Comment: I think I will go with the flow and create REST api

Answer (score 2):

You could use cross-platform [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) library to implement [HTTP server](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html), it is really straightforward with this framework, and they have a lot of examples. You can also use JSON serialization (like rapidjson library) to implement REST service on top of HTTP - this way your Web service will be accesable by most of the modern Web frameworks.

Comment: Thanks!! I think this is what I want. Just a quick question, do you think poco has Postgre support?

Comment: I'm not sure Poco supports Postgre.. In past I used soci library to talk to databases, it supports Postgre amongst the others.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [C++ Rest SDK](https://casablanca.codeplex.com), an open source, cross platform API from Microsoft.

Comment: I think C++ Rest SDK is to **use** web services. I want to prepare these type of web services

Comment: I believe the `http_listener` class https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HTTP%20Listener&referringTitle=Documentation is intended for use building a server but I haven't worked with it myself.

Comment: Casablanca documentation is poor (a little better than pion) and the design doesn't inspire much confidence (uses Asio, which is portable, but has a `web::http::experimental::listener::http_linux_server` class).

Comment: I just checked on home page. It says it can be used to build HTTP server. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Like @nogard suggested, I also recommend [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) for now. It's the most serious and feature-full solution. Given you mentioned Qt, I suggest you to take a look at [Tufão](https://github.com/vinipsmaker/tufao).

### EDIT:

I forgot to mention [one comparison of mine on the C++ HTTP server frameworks](https://github.com/vinipsmaker/gsoc2014-boost/blob/master/other_frameworks.md).

Answer (score 0):

If you directly handle HTTP requests, you might loose the functionality what Web Servers does well what it was build to do. I had a similar issue, what I did was wrap up my Qt c++ code inside a PHP extension. In your case you can do the same. Wrap your logic inside what ever technology you are about to use, doesn't matter it's PHP, net , Java or anything else.

Comment: I had the same idea initially, but I couldn't find a good example. Mostly they use .Net stack and use managed c++ code. Could you share some good resources for this approach?

Comment: If you are referring to php extension.

Just forget about Qt part, Your code is c++. C++ code can wrap up to a php extension. I used http://www.php-cpp.com/ library for writing my extension.